# how to set domain for a many2one field using one2many field

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I want to set domain for journal_id in XML. I used One2many field to get the ids of journal_id and set domain as `('id','in',journal_voucher_id)` but it throws an error

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

following is the python code:

```py
journal_voucher_id=fields.One2many('account.journal',compute='default_journalid')

@api.depends('company_id')
def default_journalid(self):
    journal_obj = self.env['account.journal']
    journal_ids = journal_obj.search([('company_id','=',self.company_id.id)])
    self.journal_voucher_id=journal_ids
```

and XML  code is as follows:

```xml
<field name="journal_id" position="after">
    <field name="journal_voucher_id" invisible="1"/>
</field>

<xpath expr="/form/sheet/group/group/field[@name='journal_id']" position="replace">
    <field name="journal_id" domain="[('type','in',['bank', 'cash']),('id','in',journal_voucher_id)]"
           widget="selection" on_change="onchange_journal(journal_id, line_cr_ids, False, partner_id, date, amount, type, company_id, context)" string="Payment Method"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Have you got the answer?@Lakshmi

Comment: No, I haven't  @Naveen

Comment: If you got means post here@lakshmi